# Give an example of a non-separable subspace of a separable space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separable-spaces

I'm trying to find an example of a non-separable subspace of a separable space.

What kind of examples are there?

Comment: The standard example is the antidiagonal in the Sorgenfrey plane (if I remember the name correctly).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space) mentions that subspace of a separable space need not be separable and lists some examples.

Answer (score 35):

If you don't care about separation axioms (e.g. Hausdorff, etc.) then you can take the following example:

$\Bbb R$ with the topology defined as $U$ is open if and only if $0\in U$ or $U=\varnothing$. Then $\{0\}$ is dense in this topology so the space is separable.

But $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is discrete (since given $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ the set $\{x,0\}$ is open, so $\{x\}$ is relatively open). And uncountable discrete spaces cannot be separable.

Comment: Can you explain why a discrete topology is not separable?

Comment: Because $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is uncountable?

Comment: I think _separable_ here means that has a countable subset which is dense.

Comment: @Matt: You're right about that. And uncountable discrete spaces are not separable.

Comment: In a discrete space, no set is dense but the space itself--every subset is already closed in the space.

Answer (score 7):

Antidiagonal (i.e. $(x,-x)$) of Sorgenfrey plane or $(x,0)$ in the Nemytskii plane both work.